# In Dogville 2003, what's the purpose of "Dictum ac factum" that's written on the mine?

Tags: dogville

In Dogville - 2003, in a brief scene, there's a writing on the wall of the mine that reads "dictum ac factum" which in Latin means "said and done". I suppose it's mentioning what the villagers have said and done to Grace but what's the purpose of it and why is it written on the wall of the mine?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it refers to the idea (central to the movie) that, when all is "said and done", people, who appeared so nice at first, will have shown their true colors?.

Do you remember at what stage of the movie this is?.

Comment: the last day, when Grace has a sleepover and then finds everyone being nice to her. Tom then talks to her and the writing is seen in that scene.